# libgdx can't drag com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window

Tags: java, window, libgdx, drag

I create a window ,but it can't be dragged. This is my code:

```
Window.WindowStyle style=new Window.WindowStyle();
style.titleFont=Context.assetMng.get("data/font/chinese.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
style.titleFontColor=Color.WHITE;
style.background=new NinePatchDrawable(new NinePatch(Context.assetMng.get("data/images/surface/window.png",Texture.class)));
bag=new Window("1111", style);
bag.padTop(10);
```

Can someone tell me the problem?

Comment: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Window.html#setMovable(boolean) ?

Comment: I add this "bag.setMovable(true); " but it still doesn't work. I saw the source code of Window. By default movable is true.

Comment: did you set up the input processor to the stage?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to take padTop (title area) as a draggable "listener", so I tried higher padtop (bag.padTop(100)) and it becomes easier to touch "title" area and drag window arround.